# In Unity how do you send a message (sync a var, call a command) from Client to server without using the player object

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity-networking

I have a multiplayer unity game (actually it is a two player game),
One player runs as `host` and the second one connects as client.
But I want to client to choose which scene to load.
Which means I need to either use a `[Command]` to do so.
But I run into client authority issues and get this error: `Trying to send command for object without authority.`

If I try to set the objects local authority I get: `AssignClientAuthority can only be call on the server for spawned objects.`

Even if I remove the authority and reset it it ends up with the same owner.

I have tried sending messages using `SendAll` too.

So is there another way that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no clean way of doing this without using the player object. What I have done is to give the player object a component that simply routes function calls to the relevant objects on the server side. No logic for the function is executed in this player component, it simply passes the call.

Comment: Thanks @Dean Johnson yes I ended up with a workaround too. I embedded an simple http server as a component onto an empty game object and can send custom commands back and forth.